# Python: Multiple infinite Loops on RaspberryPi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I wrote a function to let a LED blink with variable parameters.
The code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from threading import Thread


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

def blink(port, hz):
    """ Funktion zum Blinken von LEDs auf unterschiedlichen GPIO Ports und unterschiedlicher Hz angabe"""
    GPIO.setup(port, GPIO.OUT)
    while True:
        GPIO.output(port, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(0.5/hz)
        GPIO.output(port, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(0.5/hz)

blink(16, 5)
```

As far the code works well. 
Now I want to call the blink() function a second time with different parameters:

```
...
blink(16, 5)
blink(15, 10)
```

But with the first function calls a infinite Loop , the second call of blink() does not work. Is there a way to start a second infinite loop?

Comment: Fix your variable names

Comment: `hz` versus `hertz` ?

Comment: Looks like someone discovered a use case for multithreading

Comment: sorry, edited..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you've imported `Thread`, so something like this might do the trick(with a grain of salt here, I don't have my rpi around so I can't test it):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from threading import Thread


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

def blink(port, hz):
    """ Function to let LEDs blink with different parameters"""
    GPIO.setup(port, GPIO.OUT)
    while True:
        GPIO.output(port, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(0.5/hz)
        GPIO.output(port, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(0.5/hz)

Thread(target=blink, args=(16, 5)).start()
Thread(target=blink, args=(15, 10)).start()
```

Comment: but now I have the problem that I can´t stop it with Ctrl-C

Comment: @Kai ah, that's a different story. Keyboard interrupts are a bit more complicated when you introduce threads. You will need to make a queue for that. [This](https://christopherdavis.me/blog/threading-basics.html) is a good guide on where to start.